# JS-Ctypes in newly updated Firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

After an update last week (mid November, 2012) the enablePrivelege does not work any longer in Firefox, due to security reasons.

Therefore, web applications which were using JS-Ctypes don't work any longer.
However, I read that JS-Ctypes works using it in extensions.

So here comes the questions, does the JS-Ctypes work in extension after the new update?

Thank you!

Comment: For FF 19.0 and SDK 1.13.2 is still working.

Comment: too bad it doesn't work if you use jsctypes not in addons, but directly from your web application enabling it by

netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

There was a workaround for FF 17 - adding code to prefs.js, but it doens't work on FF 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested JS-Ctypes with newest FF (17.0.1) and Addon-SDK (1.12) and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. I haven't seen any problem with mine.